# .venv indicator may not be present in the terminal prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

After updating, I encountered an error with Visual Studio Code that was working fine before.

```
Python virtual environment was successfully activated, even though
"(.venv)" indicator may not be present in the terminal prompt.
```

When I installed venv in VS using Ctrl+Shift+P > Create Environment, I opened the terminal and it used to automatically add venv before the path. However, now it's not set and an error message appears.

then i used "notepad $PROFILE" command in cmd and add inside that Microsoft powershell profile file this text `.\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1`

It automatically displays an error message when PowerShell is turned on, which I never wanted.

[image]

[image]

I tried almost everything, including reinstalling Visual Studio and Python, but nothing worked.
Then I synced my account to Visual Studio and it automatically came back again.
I even ran the PowerShell script

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned`

but still faced the issue.

Finally, I tried disabling all extensions from VS, but the problem persisted.

Comment: At one point I swore that my terminals would show that the python virtual environment was activated. It has been awhile since I've been actively developing in VScode and I haven't paid much attention to the python updates.

Comment: Similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78005138/13642249) and possible feature if enough attention to the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22917#issue-2135988396)

Answer (score 1):

This was [a known issue in github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22822).

You could try to switch to pre-release version of python extension in extension store and try again.

Comment: tried not working.